# PHP include or MySQL fetch

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic learning site and on the navigation bar there is a category list (in form of tree, like main categories and their children) with around 30+ categories, which may increase, but not by much.

On every page I retrieve them from the database, then using PHP I do a tree like calculation to order them into a tree (parent, then children).

I feel like it's unnecessary to do it every time, so I want to cache it. But it's only like 30 or maximum 100 categories, so is it worth it to cache them?

### So I want to know which of these methods is faster:

1. Get them from MySQL and then do a calculation in PHP
2. Do step ( 1 ) once, each time a category is deleted, added, or updated, and store the result in an HTML file. Then every other time a page is loaded the app will check and include the file if it exists, or do step ( 1 ) again.

Note: Every time a category is deleted, added, or updated, the cache file is deleted.

Comment: only 100% fail safe way to know is ....... Benchmark it  your self.

Comment: You could use memcache(d).

Comment: "*But it's only like 30 or maximum 100 categories, so is it worth it to cache them?*" those numbers mean nothing in a question here really, it all depends on how long they take on average, how often the data can change etc etc. Cache is only good if it can be unchanged for an amount of time that makes it worthwhile above querying each time.

Comment: the categories doesn't change often maybe once a month or year, or perhaps never, but I still want to know which way is better because I want to use them for more complicated and bigger data

Comment: Keep in mind that there might be a significant constant cost to some method that is theoretically faster. I.e. what is faster with a smaller data set might not scale well. (e.g. extreme case: quick sort vs. selection sort on a set of 3 elements) The best way to get a good idea of what is best in any given situation is to test with a data set that is on the order of your real data.

Comment: I'd do it the latter, however I would only cache json data. This way layout is not determined by cache files. However this requires more code, and more code is harder to maintain. So if you perhaps later wanna add other cache data create a system for it now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why using files? 

Usually **server-side caching** is the better solution in this scenario. But also you can use javascript to cache it on the **client-side** using local-storage in browsers. So you can retrieve the menu directly from a local storage.

You can use
[localForage Library](https://github.com/localForage/localForage)
to store data on the client-side

Comment: glad to help :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try writing two stand-alone PHP programs (i.e. programs that you can execute by running `$ php script_name.php` on the command line) that do one of these methods respectivley. You can then use the `time` utility (assuming you're programming on macOS or a flavor of Linux) like so:

```
$ time php script_name.php
```

to see how long it takes to execute the script.

Admittedly, this is a pretty rough way to do benchmarking. If you're serious about this, take a look at [xdebug's profiler](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler). That looks like what you might need.